# NUnit3 with SpecFlow runs in VS and as batch command but not in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nunit, specflow

I have my selenium tests written using SpecFlow(+SpecRun) and NUnit framework (v.3.8.1.0). I've configured Jenkins to run these tests. My Jenkins Windows Batch Command is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.ConsoleRunner\3.7.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe"
C:\Projects\Selenium\ClassLibrary1\PortalTests\bin\Debug\PortalTests.dll
--test=TransactionTabTest;result="%WORKSPACE%\TestResults\TestR.xml";format=nunit3
```

When I trigger build test seems to start running as I'm getting as far as end of NUNIT3-CONSOLE [inputfiles] [options] with spinner indicating that test is running but it actually never ends and estimated remaining time is: N/A.

Now, when I run this script with windows cmd.exe:

```
"[PATH to Console.exe]\nunit3-console.exe" PortalTests.dll -- test=TransactionTabTest
```

this test pass successfully and so does in VS.

Now, I know this is very generic question but any clues will be much appreciated.

Comment: if you use SpecFlow+Runner/SpecRun, why are you executing the tests via nunit3-console at all?

Comment: My bad. Seems I didn't get the idea behind these runners. I just realize this when I install new NUnit3 Console GUI and tried to run test there which actually failed due to "System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I'm searching for SpecRun commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using SpecFlow+Runner/Specrun, you can find the documentation how to configure it for the different build servers here: http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-Build-Servers/

Comment: So I ended up with SpecRun tests working with batch. I will mark your answer as correct as it put me on the right track.

Comment: If you run it as batch command, be sure to use the buildserverrun parameter and not the run.
Check also the possibility from the documentation. Executing via vstest will give you a better integration into Jenkins

Comment: By vstest you mean https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/VsTestRunner+Plugin?showComments=true ?

Comment: Yes, this task. As described here http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-Jenkins/  at step 15